# New job - Is it common to ask if they offer a laptop?

Tags: software-industry, job-offer, new-job

I signed an early contract with a startup as a software developer, but they did not mention if they are going to offer equipments like a laptop (since I will be doing some work from home).

Is it something obvious that most start-ups do? Can I negotiate for a company laptop?

Comment: "*Should I?*" is typically off-topic. How would we know whether having a company laptop is important enough for you to negotiate for one? And every company will have different policies on this, start-up or not.

Comment: @Lilienthal Your top-answered tag is professionalism, which mainly deals with questions of "how should I...". I really don't see how this question is off-topic.

Comment: @michaelsnowden - 2nd close reason: Questions asking for advice on what to do are not practical answerable questions (e.g. "what job should I take?", or "what skills should I learn?"). Questions should get answers explaining why and how to make a decision, not advice on what to do.

Comment: @Lilienthal I changed it to "is it common?"

Comment: @michaelsnowden "*How should I?*" **<>** "*Should I?*". OP: unanswerable for the reason I gave. I think what you're asking about would be better phrased as "Can I ask about the equipment I'll be working with?", "Can I ask if the company provides laptops to its developers?" or "Can I negotiate for a company laptop?". Keep in mind that company laptops are typically not for personal use, hence why considering it a benefit would be strange unless you're asking from a practical standpoint (working remotely, working at a client, ...).

Comment: The point of this site is to ask questions that deal with professional consequences and behaviour, not getting us to make up your mind for you, which is what "Should I?" naturally leads to. "*I want to ask about X, can I do that or would it be considered strange*?" is *usually* on-topic.

Comment: VTC, ask your Company.

Comment: @Lilienthal I thought I would be a benefit since I've seen many companies promoting themselves by claiming that the employee will get a MacBook plus other benefits, so I wondered if they do the same.

Comment: @anonguest Who's "they"? And what do you mean by "the same"? Positioning a MacBook as a perk? You don't seem to have a clear question and I get the impression that you're looking for a forum not a Q&A site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't mention if the work from home was something that was originally part of the job description or just something you negotiated while applying for the job. 
i.e. did you or they initiate this part of the job?

No harm in asking, but at the end of the day, in most jobs, unless otherwise stated, the employer would provide the equipment necessary to do the work.

However, if it was you who initiated the "working from home" aspect of the job, then they may well expect you to have your own computer with the necessary Internet connectivity, etc.

Just a note though on your use of the word "offer". I think they would be *providing* it rather than *offering* it: The difference is subtle but using the word "offer" might make a more sensitive boss think you are asking them to give you your own lap-top, when in fact it will be *the company's* lap-top that you will just be using to do your work.